# Exit code (-1073741819) when i start JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, java-13

I created a new JavaFX project in Intellij IDEA 2019 but when I want to start it, the process ends with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) arises. What can be done with this?

My code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like this problem is related to a FileSystem access problem on Windows 10. Checking the access privileges granted to your IDE (try run as administrator) may help.

Comment: Thank you, it's help me!